# Trying to run Rails App with Apache/Passenger, but getting 404s

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger, mod-rails

I've installed passenger (don't know if the installation is correct) onto apache (i'm just using a development macintosh running snow leopard).

the httpd.conf file has a VirtualHost setting like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName myapp
  DocumentRoot /webapps/boom/public
  <Directory /webapps/boom/public>
    Allow from all
    Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

again, not sure if this is correct.

I can start up apache using apachectl start

and i can pull up the main page using this link (http://localhost).

However, when I try and go to one of my controller pages (I have a controller named blocks_controller.rb), I get a 404 error (http://localhost/blocks).

The apache error_log file shows => [Wed Jul 07 15:25:46 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /webapps/boom/public/blocks

I think this is something pretty simple that I'm doing wrong, but I don't know what.

Any thoughts??

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [VirtualHost problem with passenger (mod_rails)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536645/virtualhost-problem-with-passenger-mod-rails)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like Apache is not picking up the virtual host configuration so Passenger isn't in the loop. Are you sure that's all working? Apache looks a bit different in different environments so look in your OS specific locations at the Apache log files to be sure.

Comment: No, I'm not sure that it's all working.  I'm not sure what I should be looking for in the apache log files.

Comment: Have you looked at this guide? http://benr75.com/2008/04/12/setup-mod_rails-phusion-mac-os-x-leopard